# Why implicit rule is still processed?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have stylesheet that explicitly override this implicit rule:

```
<xsl:template match="*|/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

But the implicit rule is still processed.

Here is the **input.xml** file:

```
<catalog>
        <empty-element>
            <nested-empty-element/>
        </empty-element>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <list>
            <list-itme>
                <bullet>This is bullet</bullet>
            </list-itme>
        </list>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <artist>All Pacino</artist>
</catalog>
```

This is the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="catalog">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting the following output:

```
<root>Empire BurlesqueThis is bulletBob DylanAll Pacino</root>
```

The output I am expecting is:

```
<root/>
```

I have explicitly declared a template `<xsl:template match="*"/>` that tells the processor not to process other elements except `catalog`.
Why the nested elements are processed in the case above>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the nested elements are processed

They are not processed. But this:

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

returns the string-value of the `catalog` node - and:

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the
>   string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in
>   document order.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes